# Flutter can not find connected device (virtual device)

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, flutter, android-emulator

I am new in android developing. I start developing using flutter. I use Visual studio code as my code editor and using virtual device(android studio) to see the output. But, after configuring vs code and android studio, it shows the below error  message in vs code

> Failed to launch emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators
>   with the same AVD is an experimental feature. Please use -read-only
>   flag to enable this feature.

Comment: Where/when do you see this message?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny after configuring the vs code and android studio on my machine(windows), when i started debugging a flutter app for first time the error showed in vs code though i was running only one android emulator on my machine

Comment: Could you try rebooting and try again, just to eliminate any orphaned processes hanging around? If it still occurs, see if you can repro from the command line using `flutter emulators --launch`.

Comment: I was using Pixel 2 API 27 which was causing problem. Then, I download another virtual device (Pixel API 27). It worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

this is emulator problem, try pixel 3

Answer (score 0):

Work on Virtual Device Pixel 2 API 28 to be on safe side.